# NumberFormatter in as3corelib

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I can't seem to get this simple setup to work with as3corelib.

```
import com.adobe.utils.NumberFormatter;
trace(NumberFormatter.addLeadingZero(1));
```

All I get back is

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 2 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addLeadingZero through a reference with static type Class.
```

Using the string utilities works great, but the same doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: How are you compiling your SWF, via `mxmlc` or Flash Professional?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a NumberFormatter object first like this

```
var formatter:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter();
```

Then call

```
trace(formatter.addLeadingZero(1));
```

I haven't tested this but I am guessing this is what you need to do.

Comment: I've tried this as well, but i get back
    1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.

I think it's trying to call for the older mx.NumberFormatter